# Angular Elements - multiple instances share the same service by default

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, web-component, angular-elements

I've created my own webcomponent based on angular elements. I made everything according to manual.

The sample code is:

```
    const el = createCustomElement(AppComponent, { injector: this.injector });
    customElements.define('my-widget', el);
```

I have ApplicationService as well:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ApplicationService {}
```

After all when I run my pretty 'my-widget' element - 1 instance works well. But if I run twice it looks like the ApplicationService always run only once (singleton instance).

Example:

```
<my-widget id="widget1"></my-widget>
<my-widget id="widget2"></my-widget>
```

I want to achieve that every will have the own instance.
I was looking for solution and I noticed that config has additional field like: `strategyFactory` in `createCustomElement`

```
{ injector: Injector; strategyFactory?: NgElementStrategyFactory; }
```

I am not sure how to use it. Have you any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Dont' use `{ providedIn: 'root' }`, this registers the service as a singleton at app level. If you need new instance for each component, use the `providers[]` of component.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-widget',
  providers: [ApplicationService]
})
export class MyWidgetComponent
```

Comment: I had tried too, but in this service I need to use HttpClient and I have http interceptors which are configured in App Module and is using that service `ApplicationService` In that case Interceptor does not see one... of course it is good point but there is more requirements to fulfill